# Over a ring without unity: A module is injective iff every certain exact sequence splits.

Tags: ring-theory, modules, injective-module

In this question let us assume that $R$ is a ring without unity.

Here are two conditions for an $R$-module $J$.

**(a).** $J$ is **injective**, that is, given any $R$-module monomorphism $g:A\to B$ and a homomorphism $f:A\to J$, there is an $R$-module homomorphism $h:B\to J$ such that $f=h\circ g$.

**(b).** Every exact sequence $ 0 \to J \to A \to B \to 0 $ of $R$-modules splits.

**Question.** Does (b) imply (a)?

If $R$ had a unity then the answer is yes; what if $R$ has no unity? I'm working with the exercise IV.3.1 in *Algebra* by Hungerford. It asks to prove that

> Every short exact sequence of $R$-modules splits if and only if every $R$-module is injective.

Then it might be helpful if the answer to my question is yes.

In this book, a ring may not have a unity. The definition of injective module also does not require for a ring to have unity.

Comment: What is your definition of "injective"? There are many equivalent definitions.

Comment: A book talking about injectives/projectives in rings without identity would not be impossible, but highly improbable. Please double check your context to see if it isn't an unnecessarily exotic case to consider.