# A module $J$ is injective iff every short exact sequence of the form $0\to J\to A\to B\to 0$ splits.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, homological-algebra, exact-sequence, injective-module

A module $J$ is injective iff every short exact sequence of the form $0\to J\to A\to B\to 0$ splits.

I have seen these similar questions [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4143441/over-a-ring-without-unity-a-module-is-injective-iff-every-certain-exact-sequenc), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4236769/using-the-result-that-short-exact-sequence-is-split-exact-to-prove-that-module-i?rq=1), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1877465/q-is-an-injective-module-iff-injections-from-q-always-split), but none contain a proof of this statement above.

Here is my definition of injective module: An ($R$-)module $J$ is injective if for any injection $A\xrightarrow{f} B$ of modules and any map $A\xrightarrow{g} J$, there exists a map $B\xrightarrow{h} J$ such that $h\circ f = g$.

For the forward direction of this statement, it is easy enough. Suppose $J$ is injective. Then for any injection $J \xrightarrow{f} A$, there exists a map $A\xrightarrow{g} J$ such that $g \circ f = \operatorname{id}_J$. So by the splitting lemma, the short exact sequence splits.

However, the reverse direction seems more complicated. We assume that every such sequence splits, and need to show that $J$ is injective. I think this should require more work than a simple application of the definition. Namely, we start with an arbitrary injection $A\xrightarrow{f}B$ and map $A\xrightarrow{g}J$ and need to come up with a map $B\xrightarrow{h} J$ such that $h\circ f = g$. This means we somehow need to convert these maps into a short exact sequence of the given form, and then maybe use the splitting lemma to get the desired map.

I've thought about this for a while, but cannot see how to get a short exact sequence of the above form out of this information. What is the key idea for this direction of the proof?

Comment: I remember reading Dummit and Foote and there were 3 equivalent conditions for injective module. Equivalence of one of the statements was much harder to prove. I am not sure if it was this one but you can check it out.

Comment: @TonyPizza I just checked this, and my question is the same as the statement $(3)\implies (2)$ in D&F Prop. 34 (Chapter 10). However, the authors write that the proof is "outlined in the exercises," so unfortunately this doesn't help find the solution.

Comment: That's what I was talking about. The one that's outlined in the excercises is harder one. Even if you read excercise you'll see you need long series of them to prove it.